# Display NSWindow as Subview of NSView

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard, nsview, nib

I have an NSWindow that I want to display as part of another window. It has to be an NSWindow; I don't want to change it to an NSView or anything... I just don't because it involves accessing foreign nib files and the such.

How should I accomplish this if possible? I was thinking along the lines of grabbing the view of the NSWindow and sticking it as the subview of another view in my main window... but I don't think this is possible. Is it?

Comment: If you're OK with grabbing a view out of the window, it sounds like it *doesn't* have to be an NSWindow.

Comment: Well, I want to take the view out of the NSWindow since... first of all the NSWindow I want to incorporate isn't even part of my app. It's in an external nib file that I don't want to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with the window as-is, just add it as a child window to the window in your own app. That will handle positioning and everything, although you might have to patch up the responder chain and such to really get things working properly.